# Equal substring value does not return expected result

Tags: java, android

Hi I have a problem with this substring where I expected it to be equal. Well I made a function where you will compare two names then whenever those names share a same character it will change all that characters into spaces. Can you check where is my mistake in this one? I'm having a hardtime to figure it out. Here's my code:

```
name1 = name1.replace(" ","");
    name2 = name2.replace(" ","");

    Log.v(TAG, name1);
    Log.v(TAG, name2);

    Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(name1.length()));
    Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(name2.length()));

    for (int x=0; x < name1.length(); x++){
        for (int y=0; y < name2.length(); y++){

            Log.v(TAG, "Value of LOOP : "+"-"+String.valueOf(y) +"-"+String.valueOf(x)+"-");
            Log.v(TAG,"-"+name1.substring(x)+"-"+name2.substring(y)+"-");

            if (name1.substring(x) == name2.substring(y)){
                Log.v(TAG, "Value of XY : "+String.valueOf(y)+","+String.valueOf(y));

                name1 = name1.replace(name1.substring(x)," ");
                name2 = name2.replace(name2.substring(y)," ");
            }
        }
     }
    Log.v(TAG,"LOOP SUCCESS");

    String name3 = name1 + name2;
    Log.v(TAG,"Name 3 Value: "+name3);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare two `String` variables. Use the `equals()` method.

```
if (name1.substring(x).equals(name2.substring(y))) {
    ...
```

Comment: Oh, and how about if NOT EQUAL?

Comment: Just negate the condition. `if (!name1.substring(x).equals(name2.substring(y))) {`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't compare Java strings with ==, use equals() instead. Basically you have two objects that have the same value. Operator == tests if two references point to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

String/Object comparison in java is `.equals()` not `==`

```
if (name1.substring(x).equals(name2.substring(y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, whenever you want to compare the actual data of two String objects you should use `.equals()` Using `==` will only compare if the two sides are identical objects (in other words if they are the same memory location).

Here's some code that may help you understand

```
String s = "Hello";
String d = "Hello";

System.out.println(s.equals(d)); // Prints out true
System.out.println(s == d); // Prints out false

String newS = s;

System.out.println(s.equals(newS); // Prints out true, the data is still the same
System.out.println(s == newS); // Prints out true because they are the same object
```

`.equalsIgnoreCase()` works the same way but `"Hello"` and `"hello"` will be read as equal Strings.

Comment: First time I've heard of the equalsIgnoreCase(). Thank you.

Comment: Actually `System.out.println(s == d);` will print out `true` as well because the compiler recognizes that you used the string literal "Hello" twice and allocates only one object for it. To prove your point you have to trick it by using something like `String d = new String("Hello");`.